# Импортировать целый пакет или только нужные классы?

Tags: java, синтаксис, импорт, пакет, syntax

Как лучше делать, импортировать целый пакет (удобно):

```
import java.io.*;
```

Или импортировать только те классы, которые необходимы для работы кода?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это спорный вопрос. С одной стороны многие команды разработчиков используют замечательное правило  "Заимпортил звёздочку - получил по мордочке", так как явные импорты лучше передают намерения программиста и не "пачкают" пространство имён лишними определениями. Да и линтер ругаться будет как с Sun'овскими правилами, так и с Google'вскими. А с другой стороны Роберт Мартин в своём хрестоматийном труде "Чистый код" выступает за *звёздный импорт*, так как это позволяет избавиться от длинных "пелёнок" в начале листинга и тем самым снизить количество "шума".

Comment: Аргумент дяди Боба растет из тех времен, когда код писали в обычном текстовом редакторе. В наши дни любая нормальная ИДЕ может сворачивать эти пеленки и тем самым вообще снижать шум до нуля.

Comment: А на производительность программы, память и т. п. влияет?

Comment: [Нет, не влияет.](https://toster.ru/q/522885)